# Solr Admin console not returning search results

Tags: solr, solr6

I have a Solr 6 instance deployed on the cloud and have 3 cores. All three cores are functional, in the sense

1. I am able to view the schema
2. I am able to add documents programmatically (via Solarium for PHP)
3. I am able to search documents programatically (via Solarium)

However, when I click on 'query' menu under the core and run a generic query via the admin console - `http://192.192.192.192/solr/#/cars/query` - it returns an error message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /solr/cars/select was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

But if I run the same query via the link `http://192.192.192.192/solr/cars/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json`

I get all the results - what am I doing wrong?

I have tried reloading the cores, I have tried restarting the Solr server. I have restarted the Apache server.. no avail. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is apache used in all of this? Is Solr started on port 80 or area you going through Apache. I assume http://<your server>/solr/#/cars/plugins/queryhandler looks ok?

Comment: Yes, Solr is on port 80. This is a dedicated server for Solr - so no port conflict. Yes the queryhandler looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to open Browser's developer/debugger panel and see what URL is getting actually requested in the Net (or similar) panel.

My guess without seeing that output is that maybe your server is reporting itself running on a different address, so the Admin UI uses the reported address (e.g. localhost) instead of the correct one. And, for some reason, you do have something running on that server and it reports an error.

Comment: The console (Chrome) says the following - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://192.192.192.192/solr/cars%2Fselect?_=1465747101051&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json `

Comment: Seems like the problem is being caused by `/select` being escaped as `%2Fselect` - any suggestions on where / how to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Is there a proxy? If so, this might be a bug fixed in 6.0.1/6.1 [SOLR-8870](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8870). If you can't upgrade, you might be able to work around it with a regex replace on the proxy side.